# Can we add a sub menu item to a dependent extension menu from current extension in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to add a sub menu item to a dependent extension menu from my extension. Is it a possible scenario?

I have tried to add the dependent extension id in my package.json

`"extensionDependencies": [ "publisher.name" ],`

Comment: where is that `extension menu`

Comment: in the extension that is marked as dependent.

Comment: how can an extension create a menu